# Autopost RSS feed to Twitter apps?

Tags: twitter, rss

I'm using http://twitterfeed.com/ but the 5 posts/30 minutes limit is really a pain.

Is there a way to autotweet more than this with another application?
Or a way to exceed the limit in twitterfeed?

Answer (score 2):

You could try [dlvr.it](http://dlvr.it/)